# How to delete a respondent from a survey in version 3 of the API

Tags: curl, surveymonkey

I wish to get the respondents of a survey (which works great).  Along with the information that I get about their answers, I also get the respondent_id.  After processing the answers, I want to delete that respondent.  What I am sending is:

!curl --silent -i -X DELETE -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:bearer *AuthKey*" https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/86562851/responses/2937452447

I get back information about the survey and respondent, but the respondent is not deleted.  Here is the start of what I get back:

{"total_time":139,"href":"https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/86562851/responses/2937452447","custom_variables":{},"ip_address":"107.0.172.83","id":"2937452447","logic_path":{},"date_modified":"2013-11-22T21:48:05+00:00","response_status":"completed","custom_value":"", ...

I obviously have not formed my command correctly.  How should the transaction be formed to delete a respondent from a survey.

Thanks

Comment: SysJames, when you do a `GET` right after that request, does it return a 404? All `DELETE` requests always return back the resource you just deleted to show you which resource was deleted. Trying to fetch it after that will raise an error.

Comment: Performing the delete (same as in the question), then doing a get (only changing the word "DELETE" to "GET" in the command, The first part of what I get back is: {"total_time":139,"href":"https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/86562851/responses/2937452447","custom_variables":{},"ip_address":"107.0.172.83","id":"2937452447","logic_path":{},"date_modified":"2013-11-22T21:48:05+00:00","response_status":"completed","custom_value":"",...  I do not get back a 404.  If I ask for all respondents to the survey, my deleted respondent is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The API transaction as shown now works.  I submitted the problem to SurveyMonkey support.  They say they didn't change anything, but the command as originally coded works now.